# Gallery with thumbnails and a big image preview

Tags: android, image, thumbnails, android-gallery

I'd like to create a gallery like this which has bar with small images and a big preview: [image: gallery]

The point is that I'd like to have some preloading of images etc, so I found [Android Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader), but it doesn't seem it has the possibility of the top bar with image thumbnails. Could you please give me some hints how it could be modified to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have already done it using [horizontal ListView](http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34)

Comment: Dear @Krivers I have the same issue you have above. because of the posted link is broken, can you give any directions for me to follow. thanks in advance.

Comment: the above link is broken